# Hilo in c# console app with nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Having a console app which which many will start over and over again
and using hilo. Everytime the app is started and the sessionfactory is rebuilt the hilo columns (next_hi) will be increased and a reserved space with ids will be lost.

Have anybody had any experience with this?

Could't that be a nice feature for the hilo-generator to optionally
remember the high and low-values for applications often being shutdown
by many users? I mean it have already reserved a space of ids, which
in that environment often isn't fully utilized.

Thank you for sharing your experiences in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Int64 max value is 9223372036854775807.
Lets assume that each application start you will insert one record and lose 99 ids.
it means you have 9223372036854775807 / 100 = 92233720368547758 effective ids.

Lets assume you applications inserts 50000 records per second into database.

92233720368547758 / 50000 = 184467440737095.51614 seconds = 2135039823.346012918287037037037 days = 5930666 years.

Are you still worried?